# FIND_IN_SET slow, can't use IN()

Tags: mysql

I have a stored procedure and it's running slow. Is there a better way to pass the table id's to the procedure rather that use FIND_IN_SET?

The table column e.fk_trans_history_id is an INT(32)

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `1_trans_hist_ent_items_sel`(b INT,tid TEXT)
BEGIN
SELECT 
    e.id,
    e.fk_trans_history_id,
    e.fk_prod_pack_id,
    e.line_num,
    e.vat_code,
    e.code,
    e.make,
    e.model,
    e.price,
    e.discount,
    e.cover,
    e.warranty,
    p.make,
    p.model,
    p.weight,
    p.width,
    p.depth,
    p.height,
    p.cost,
    p.cover_value_each,
    p.web_model,
    k.stock - k.repair
FROM
    1_trans_history_entries e
        LEFT JOIN
    1_products p ON p.id = e.fk_prod_pack_id
        AND LEFT(code, 1) <> 'P'
        LEFT JOIN
    1_stock k ON k.fk_products_id = p.id AND k.branch = b
WHERE
    (e.code IN ('MiscShip' , 'Collect')
        OR (ASCII(e.code) > 47
        AND ASCII(e.code) < 58))
        AND FIND_IN_SET(e.fk_trans_history_id, tid)
ORDER BY e.id;
END
```

Comment: Sow sample data please and expected result.

Comment: What do you put in tid?A comma delimited string?

Comment: Why can't you use in ?

Comment: yes tid is a comma delim list of id's as text

Comment: can't use IN as I can't see any way of parsing this to the procedure

Comment: Fix the data structure to use a junction table so you can take advantage of SQL, which is optimized for tables and not for strings.

Comment: You can simply make use of CONCAT() or REPLACE(). Both can be used to achieve your purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the IDs you want to match into a temporary table, and join with that table.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_trans_hist_ent_items_sel_ids (
    id
);
INSERT INTO temp_trans_hist_ent_items_sel_ids VALUES (1), (10), ...;
```

Then the query in the procedure can use:

```
JOIN temp_trans_hist_ent_items_sel_ids AS temp ON e.fk_trans_history_id = temp.id
```

Comment: thats an idea, if I've got a transaction running, will the creation of the temp table cause a commit?

Comment: I'm not really sure, but I think it unlikely.

Comment: I've created the temp table inside the procedure. How do I insert the values from the TEXT list in to it?

Comment: You could write a `WHILE` loop that uses `SUBSTRING_INDEX` to extract each element of the text list. But what I intended is that you get rid of the text list entirely. Whatever creates that list should just put the data into the temporary table instead, before calling the function.

Answer (score 2):

I found the best and the fastest is to prepare a query like this.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `1_trans_hist_ent_items_sel`(b INT, tid TEXT)
BEGIN
--
SET @query=CONCAT( '
SELECT 
    e.id,
    e.fk_trans_history_id,
    e.fk_prod_pack_id,
    e.line_num,
    e.vat_code,
    e.code,
    e.make,
    e.model,
    e.price,
    e.discount,
    e.cover,
    e.warranty,
    p.make,
    p.model,
    p.weight,
    p.width,
    p.depth,
    p.height,
    p.cost,
    p.cover_value_each,
    p.web_model,
    k.stock - k.repair
FROM
    1_trans_history_entries e
        LEFT JOIN
    1_products p ON p.id = e.fk_prod_pack_id
        AND LEFT(code, 1) <> \'P\'
        LEFT JOIN
    1_stock k ON k.fk_products_id = p.id AND k.branch = ',b,'
WHERE
    (e.code IN (\'MiscShip\' , \'Collect\')
        OR (ASCII(e.code) > 47
        AND ASCII(e.code) < 58))
        AND e.fk_trans_history_id IN(' , tid , ')
        ORDER BY e.id;');
--
PREPARE sql_query FROM @query;
EXECUTE sql_query;
--
SET @query = '';
--
END
```

Comment: No risk os sql injection ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Stephen Bouffe. My code is shorter and it would be easier to understand and implement this solution. In my case, it looks like this

```
SET @query=CONCAT( '
    DELETE FROM markup
    WHERE id IN (', @ids, ');
');

PREPARE sql_query FROM @query;
EXECUTE sql_query;
```

Where @ids is a string like '7,12,52'.
It works **significantly faster** then FIND_IN_SET.